# How do I randomly fill my list with zeros and ones such that their number is equal?

Tags: python, random

This is what I am doing right now:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *

K=np.array([np.random.choice([1,0]) for i in range(20)])
print(K)
```

The OUTPUT gives:

```
[1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
```

I want to fill this list like above where the positions for ones and zeros are random but the above method does not render them to be equal in number. I understand why this happens. The "choice" randomly chooses from 1 and 0 so there is no reason for them to be equal in number in the list. But if I want them to be randomly chosen and still be equal in number (10 ones and 10 zeros for the above case) what do I do?

Comment: you could fill it with 10 contiguous 0s and 10 contiguous 1s and then shuffle https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *

K = np.zeros(20, dtype=int)
K[:10] = 1
np.random.shuffle(K)
print(K)
```

i.e. first create an array with equal numbers of contiguous `1`s and `0`s, then randomise the order.

Comment: Hi. With this method I get 1s and 0s as floats like 1.0 and 0.0 which I don't want. I tried to put int but it doesn't work

Comment: have to specify the dtype of the numpy array, I've updated the answer with that... can be seen working here: https://trinket.io/python3/0c5ac62d76

Answer (score 0):

Build a list comprised of an equal number of zeroes and ones. Take a pseudo-random sample. Construct array. For example:

```
from random import sample
from numpy import array

N = 20
list_ = [0] * (N//2) + [1] * (N//2)
K = array(sample(list_, k=N))
print(K)
```

**Sample output:**

```
[1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]
```